# Centering Vdots in a table?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[hbt]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |>{\centering} p{1cm}|>{\centering}p{2cm}|>{\centering}p{2cm}|>{\centering}p{2cm}| >{\centering}p{2cm} | >{\centering}p{2cm}| >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} | } 

        \hline
             $n$ & $x_n$ & $e_n$ & $y_n$ & $f_n$ & $z_n$ & $h_n$ \\
             \hline
             14 & 14 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 12 \tabularnewline
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline

             \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
             
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline

             \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

How to centre vdots in the table?

[image: latex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The simplest solution would be to change all instances of `\vdots` to `$\vdots$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a very minimum, you need to change all instances of `\vdots` to `$\vdots$`; the result of making this change is shown in the first table below.

Your setup, which employs absolute rather than relative column widths, in no way guarantees that the table will fit within the width of the text block. In fact, as the screenshot demonstrates, it far exceeds the available width.

To assure that the table will, in fact, fit properly while also assuring equal widths of the six data columns, I suggest you switch to a `tabularx` environment; see the lower table for the resulting "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption{Minimalist solution: Replace \texttt{\string\vdots} with \texttt{\$\string\vdots\$}\strut}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | >{\centering}p{1cm} | *{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|} } 
        \hline
        $n$ & $x_n$ & $e_n$ & $y_n$ & $f_n$ & $z_n$ & $h_n$ \\
        \hline
        14 & 14 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 12 \tabularnewline
        5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
        5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
        5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
        $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\        
        5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
        5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
        5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
        5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \tabularnewline
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption{Better solution: Switch to a \texttt{tabularx} environment\strut}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | w{c}{1cm} | *{6}{C|} } 
        \hline
        $n$ & $x_n$ & $e_n$ & $y_n$ & $f_n$ & $z_n$ & $h_n$ \\
        \hline
        14 & 14 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 12 \\
         5 &  6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
         5 &  6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
         5 &  6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
        $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\    
         5 &  6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
         5 &  6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
         5 &  6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
         5 &  6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
        \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two different versions:

Side note: As it currently is, your table is quite wide. You might want to consider decreasing column widths in order to make sure, the table does not exceed the textwidth.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{|*{7}{c|}} 

        \hline
             n & x_n & e_n & y_n & f_n & z_n & h_n \\
             \hline
             14 & 14 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 12 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\

             \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
             
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\

             \hline
    \end{array}
\]
    
    
\begin{table}[hbt]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{$}wc{1cm}<{$}|*{6}{>{$}wc{2cm}<{$}|}} 
        \hline
             n & x_n & e_n & y_n & f_n & z_n & h_n \\
             \hline
             14 & 14 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 13 & 12 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\

             \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
             
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\
             5 & 6 & 56 & 56 & 34 & 12 & 22 \\

             \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```